# Python Delete rows of matrices with bool index like matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have the following problem.

Considering I have 9 x 9 sparse identity matrix `var` and a 3x3 boolean matrix `bol`, where  the position (2,2) has the value False.

In matlab I can delete rows like this

```
    var1 = speye(9);
    bol=false(3,3);
    bol(3:3,1:3)=1;
    bol(1:3,1:1)=1;
    bol(1:1,1:3)=1;
    bol(1:3,3:3)=1;

    var1(bol(:),:)=[];
```

and I get the result

```
    var1 =
    (1,5)    1
```

How I can do this so easy in Python?

In Python I have create the variables like this:

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import sparse

    var1 = sparse.eye(9).tocsc()
    bol = np.zeros((3,3),dtype='bool')
    bol[2:3,0:3]=1
    bol[0:3,0:1]=1
    bol[0:1,1:3]=1
    bol[0:3,-1]=1
```

I also create `var1_del` in Python which is something like `var1(bol(:),)` in matlab

```
    va1_del = var1[bol.reshape(9)[:],:]
```

this was my try to delete the rows. The result is obviously wrong

```
    var1 = [x for x in var1 if not x in var_del]

    var1 =
    []
```

Do you have an idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reads a lot like someone coming from matlab to python. There are ways of pythonizing it.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

var1 = sparse.eye(9).tocsc()

# we can make our truth matrix much faster
bol = np.ones((3, 3), dtype='bool')
bol[1, 1] = False
```

In matlab to delete a row you set it to `[]`. In python we can use numpy advanced indexing like so to only keep the rows we want (`~` is the element wise `not` operator):

```
# ~bol.flatten(): array([False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False])
var1 = var1[~bol.flatten()]
```

`var1` is now:

```
repr: <1x9 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
           with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
str:  (0, 4)        1.0
```

Because we're in python each index is 1 less so this is the same as your matlab result.